# How can I animate multiple instances of drawImage() on a Canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am working with canvas animations for the first time and I am having an issue when trying to animate multiple images at once.

I am able to draw multiple images on a canvas and position them randomly. I can get a single image to animate on the canvas but only the last image drawn from an array.

I know that the issue is with clearRect() clearing all previously drawn images from said array but can't figure out how to only clearRect once all images have been drawn in each animation frame, I was wondering if anyone has dealt with something like this before and if they could point me in the right direction of how to only clearRect() after all images are drawn?

```
function animate() {
        srequestAnimationFrame(animate);

        for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            let y = images[i].y;
            let img = new Image();
            img.src = images[i].url;

            img.onload = function() {
                // This is clearing all images drawn before the last image
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.drawImage(this, images[i].x, y, images[i].width, images[i].height);
            }

            images[i].y -= 1;

            if(images[i].y < (0 - images[i].height)) {
                images[i].y = window.innerHeight;
                images[i].x = (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 160));
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to animate all the images vertically up the page with them resetting to the bottom after reaching the top of the screen, I have this working but only for the last image as mentioned above

Comment: Only do animation related actions within your `animate()` function. Loading images is initialization, not animation. Load images once in a separate function during initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `animate()` function, after updating the value for the `y` you need to draw again every image. Also, you need to clear the canvas with every frame (the `animate()` function), not after drawing every image, since `clearRect` will delete everything previously drawn on the canvas. The reason why you need to clear the rect is that you have to delete the images drawn at the previous position.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth);
cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight),
    cy = ch / 2;

let images = [
  {
    url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/puppy150x150.jpg",
    x: Math.random() * cw,
    y: Math.random() * ch,
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  },
  {
    url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/puppy200x200.jpg",
    x: Math.random() * cw,
    y: Math.random() * ch,
    width: 40,
    height: 40
  },
  {
    url:
    "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/puppyBeagle300.jpg",
    x: Math.random() * cw,
    y: Math.random() * ch,
    width: 60,
    height: 60
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  let y = images[i].y;
  images[i].img = new Image();
  images[i].img.src = images[i].url;

  images[i].img.onload = function() {
    // This is clearing all images drawn before the last image
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(this, images[i].x, y, images[i].width, images[i].height);
  };
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // clear the canvas here!
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  //update the y value
    images[i].y -= 1;
    if (images[i].y < -images[i].height) {
      images[i].y = window.innerHeight;
      images[i].x = Math.random() * (canvas.width - 160);
    }
    //draw again the image
    ctx.drawImage(
      images[i].img,
      images[i].x,
      images[i].y,
      images[i].width,
      images[i].height
    );
  }
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```